# What magnitude stars are visible during a quarter moon, during nautical twilight?

Tags: magnitude, naked-eye, twilight

Assuming I'm looking for stars at least 50° from the quarter moon, is there any way to determine what magnitude stars would be visible to the naked eye, in a sky without light pollution, during nautical twilight? ([Nautical twilight](https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/nautical-twilight.html) occurs when the geometric center of the Sun's disk is between 6 and 12 degrees below the horizon.)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_brightness might be interesting